# Copy content from double quote string to single quote string

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying copy part of a string from an element to an inline CSS string, but the quotation marks are giving me grief. I want to copy the source of:

```
<img src="/welcome/assets/images/logo.jpg">
```

to the url of:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/welcome/assets/images/tour-1.jpg');">
```

without having the double quotation marks from the first string being copied over.

Is there a way of just copying the URL using JQuery without the quotation marks being affected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to use [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to assign a css property to element. [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) will return the value of specified `attribute`

```js
$('#targetElem').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('#source').attr('src') + ')');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="source" src="/welcome/assets/images/logo.jpg">
<div id="targetElem"></div>
```